# URL encoding/decoding

Tags: c#, url, http, файлы

Добрый день!

Прошу вас подсказать мне, как можно в C# кодировать/декодировать URL. Что подключить, какие классы и их методы необходимо использовать.

И вторая часть вопроса. Как можно выделять из URL адреса или полного пути файла одно лишь его имя или путь к файлу (ну или имя диска, если имеем дело с файловой системой). Я имею ввиду, как это можно сделать ОДНОЙ функцией, как в дельфи, например:

```
Extractfilepath / ExtractfileName
```

Есть ли что-либо подобное в шарпе?

Большое вам спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По поводу работы с файлами посмотрите класс [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.path.aspx). Там есть все необходимые методы.

Comment: Отлично! Это именно то, что мне требовалось. Благодарю!

Answer (score 3):

Ну а собственно вот ответ на вопрос [по урлам](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.httputility.aspx). Есть в классе HttpUtility два волшебных метода UrlEncode/UrlDecode. Их можно заюзать. Сборка System.Web

Comment: Я уже натыкался на эту вещь, когда пытался сам отыскать решение проблемы, но тут проблема в том, что данный класс поддерживается лишь в .NET Framework 4.5 и выше. В VS2010, как вы знаете стоит 4 версия.

Comment: HttpUtility поддерживается с .NET Framework 3.5. См. статью на МСДН

Comment: Класса  HttpUtility  не было мною обнаружено в пространстве имен System.Web...

Comment: Это печально...

Comment: В свойствах проекта необходимо для поля "target framework" поставить ".NET Framework 4" вместо ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile".

Но если всё-таки Вам нужен клиентский профайл .NET-а, то используйте статические методы класса [Uri][1]:

 - [EscapeUriString][2]
 - [EscapeDataString][3]
 - [UnescapeDataString][4]


  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2z967xy0
  [2]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring
  [3]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring
  [4]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.unescapedatastring

Answer (score 0):

Но при использовании
EscapeUriString
EscapeDataString
UnescapeDataString

результат у меня пустой получается.

А когда использую HttpUtility.UrlEncode получаю нормальный результат.
А кроме этих методов есть ли другие функции с той же функциональностью?
может самому создать Dictionary(TKey, TValue), и так делать Encod/decode?:)

Заранее Спасибо.
Всем удачи